# Application context error in Flask app with Celery in Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, celery

I'm attempting to use Flask and Celery in Docker and am having issues with the Flask application context.

Flask==1.0.2
celery==4.2.0
Flask-CeleryExt==0.3.1

Here is some pertinent code.

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/dev/myapp/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
      - '8888:8888'
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    entrypoint: /wait-for-postgres.sh
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    networks:
      - flask-redis-celery

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/dev/celery/Dockerfile
    command: 'celery -A myapp.tasks worker -Q default --loglevel=info'
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - myapp
    networks:
      - flask-redis-celery
```

**extensions.py**

```
from flask_celeryext import FlaskCeleryExt
ext = FlaskCeleryExt()
```

**app.py** in a `register_extensions` function. I'm using the application factory pattern in my app.

```
ext.init_app(app)
```

Inside of the `myapp` container, I can get to `ext.celery` per the [documentation](https://flask-celeryext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#extension-initialization) and see that I have a Celery instance and correctly send a task to

```
<Celery default at 0x7f600d0e7f98>
```

However, attempting to do the same in the celery container in my `tasks` file results in `ext.celery` being None.

**tasks.py**

```
from coupon.extensions import ext
celery = ext.celery # This is None

@celery.task(name='tasks.my_task', max_retries=2, default_retry_delay=60)
def my_task(some_args):
    # etc.
```

Error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'task'
```

I've attempted numerous other options as well including `make_celery` as noted in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/), but cannot get to Flask and my models in the celery container, so do not believe this is very specific to Flask-CeleryExt.

I can make Celery tasks work fine if they do not access Flask objects, but I need to access SQLAlchemy models and custom classes from my Celery tasks.

How can I make Celery work properly in my celery container and be able to access Flask objects?